# Keypress is not working in field input in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Keypress is not working in field input in Magento 2

This is my form:
[image]

My jquery

```
$("input[name$='general[stocktaking]']").keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13') {
        //code here
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I tried `$(".admin__control-text")` but it not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `\\` in field name to because it is already in brackets `[]`

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("input[name='general\\[stocktaking\\]']").keypress(function(event){
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13') {
                //code here
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, but it not work :(

Comment: did you add it in jquery require function?

Comment: edited my answer, please check now, and make sure you run deployment script after edit

Comment: yes, i did added

Comment: Then make sure you run deployment script after you added your code

Comment: I edited it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you run this command `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Yes I am sure...

Comment: I have checked the script by myself, it's working. Either you are not using input name correctly or something else

Comment: I have used this code on my website console and it's printing in console **"here"**:
`require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("input[name='link']").keypress(function(event){
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13') {
                console.log("here");
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
});`

Comment: if use $("input[name$='general[sku]']").val(), i got value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90911/discussion-between-shoaib-munir-and-tn98).